# How can I change image source on click with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, function, href

I 'm currently building a full background image layout and I want to change the image based on which page the user is visiting. To get to the point: I need to change a images attribute when the user clickes on a link. This is how far I got:

```
$(function() {
  $('.menulink').click(function(){
    $("#bg").attr('src',"img/picture1.jpg");
  });
});
```

```
    <a href="" title="Switch" class="menulink">switch me</a>
    <img src="img/picture2.jpg" id="bg" />
```

Thank you, probably easy stuff, but over my head!

Comment: That should work. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Tejs its a prevent default issue i believe

Comment: Forgot to tell you guys, it works but as soon as it has changed the image it changes back to the first image....

Comment: @Johannes , see my answer below. it is due to the fact that ur link is making the page refresh, you need to use `preventDefault()` to stop that from happening

Comment: @Neal Ah I'll give it a try right away...

Comment: it does not give any result ([link](http://johanneskarnstam.se/new/)) :( Thanks anyways

Comment: Ahhh it wooorked.... return default made the diffrence.... Thanks a million

Comment: it worked for me... i am using chrome

Comment: @Neal.... yeah I'm game now..... thanks appreciate u spending time on this matter

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It switches back because by default, when you click a link, it follows the link and loads the page.
In your case, you don't want that. You can prevent it either by doing e.preventDefault(); (like Neal mentioned) or by returning false :

```
$(function() {
 $('.menulink').click(function(){
   $("#bg").attr('src',"img/picture1.jpg");
   return false;
 });
});
```

[Interesting question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) on the differences between prevent default and return false.

In this case, return false will work just fine because the event doesn't need to be propagated.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `preventDefault()` to make it so the link does not go  through when u click on it:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Sevdm/

```
$(function() {
 $('.menulink').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
   $("#bg").attr('src',"img/picture1.jpg");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using a button for this. Links generally should be use for **linking**. Buttons can be used for other functionality you wish to add. Neals solution works, but its a workaround.

If you use a `<button>` instead of a `<a>`, your original code should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's `attr()` function, like `$("#id").attr('src',"source")`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('div#imageContainer').click(function () {
      $('div#imageContainerimg').attr('src', 'YOUR NEW IMAGE URL HERE'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click the text or link the image will be changed to another image so you can use the below script helps to you to change image on click the link:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('li').click(function(){
var imgpath = $(this).attr('dir');
$('#image').html('<img src='+imgpath+'>');
});
$('.btn').click(function(){
$('#thumbs').fadeIn(500);
$('#image').animate({marginTop:'10px'},200);
$(this).hide();
$('#hide').fadeIn('slow');
});
$('#hide').click(function(){
$('#thumbs').fadeOut(500,function (){
$('#image').animate({marginTop:'50px'},200);
});
$(this).hide();
$('#show').fadeIn('slow');
});
});
</script>




 <div class="sandiv">
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">The  Human  Body  Parts :</h1>
    <div id="thumbs">
    <div class="sanl">
    <ul>
    <li dir="5.png">Human-body-organ-diag-1</li>
    <li dir="4.png">Human-body-organ-diag-2</li>
    <li dir="3.png">Human-body-organ-diag-3</li>
    <li dir="2.png">Human-body-organ-diag-4</li>
    <li dir="1.png">Human-body-organ-diag-5</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="man">
    <div id="image">
    <img src="2.png" width="348" height="375"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="thumbs">
    <div class="sanr" >
    <ul>
    <li dir="5.png">Human-body-organ-diag-6</li>
    <li dir="4.png">Human-body-organ-diag-7</li>
    <li dir="3.png">Human-body-organ-diag-8</li>
    <li dir="2.png">Human-body-organ-diag-9</li>
    <li dir="1.png">Human-body-organ-diag-10</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
<style>
body{ font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#ccc; font-size:11px; margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#111111}
.sandiv{ width:980px;height:570px;margin:0 auto;margin-top:20px; padding:10px; background-color:#000;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #666;box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #666;}
#image{width:348px; height:375px; border-radius:100%;margin:0 auto; margin-top:50px; margin-bottom:20px;}
#thumb{width:400px;margin:0 auto; display:none;}
ul{list-style:none; padding:0; margin:0;}
 li{ width:auto ; height:50px; border-radius:100%; margin:5px; cursor:pointer; }
.sanl
{
 margin-top:50px;
 float:left;
 width:210px;
 margin-left:30px;
 margin-right:30px;
  }
.sanr
{
    margin-top:50px;
 float:left;
 width:210px;
 margin-left:60px;
 margin-right:30px;
}
.man
{
 float:left;
 width:350px;
 margin-left:30px;
 margin-right:30px; 
}
</style>
```